# Expose different ports on host in docker-compose.yml when using --scale app=2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know that I can expose a random  port by just specifying "ports: 8080" in docker-compose.yml, but I want to either have specified ports on host exposed or get them just in integer format which is not possible using "docker port" command. Is there any way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, 1 deployment expose multiple ports like `8080:8080` and `8000:8000` at the same time?

Comment: I am running multiple services using same image, there is an application server running in each container, I want to access those both servers from host.

Comment: wait, your question include `scale` replicas, but you are using multiple service?  If it is multiple services, then you can define a different port to be exposed and access it by different ports, but your question contain `scale` replicas, if a service is `scale` to 2 replicas, two of that container will share the same port and do a Round Robin algorithm when we accessing it multiple times.